# Service account throwing SQLiteException on NServiceBus startup

Tags: sqlite, nservicebus

I'm getting the following exception when I try to start nservicebus.host.exe with service account credentials:

```
    Database was not configured through Database method.  
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Unable to open the database file  
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)  
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() in :line 0
at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare() in :line 0
at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) in :line 0
at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) in :line 0
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) in :line 0
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in D:\dev\fluent-nhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 93
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in D:\dev\fluent-nhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 100
at NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.Config.Internal.SessionFactoryBuilder.Build(IDictionary^2 nhibernateProperties, Boolean updateSchema) in c:\Dev\DotNet\NServiceBus\src\impl\SagaPersisters\NHibernateSagaPersister\NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.Config\Internal\SessionFactoryBuilder.cs:line 48
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.Config.Internal.SessionFactoryBuilder.Build(IDictionary^2 nhibernateProperties, Boolean updateSchema) in c:\Dev\DotNet\NServiceBus\src\impl\SagaPersisters\NHibernateSagaPersister\NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.Config\Internal\SessionFactoryBuilder.cs:line 55
at NServiceBus.ConfigureNHibernateSagaPersister.NHibernateSagaPersister(Configure config, IDictionary^2 nhibernateProperties, Boolean autoUpdateSchema) in c:\Dev\DotNet\NServiceBus\src\impl\SagaPersisters\NHibernateSagaPersister\NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.Config\ConfigureNHibernateSagaPersister.cs:line 80
at Ibfx.BackOffice.Services.NewAccounts.NewAccountsEndpoint.Init() in C:\Dev\TFS\Omega\Src\Svcs\NewAccounts\Src\Service\NewAccountsEndpoint.cs:line 67
at NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHost.Start() in c:\Dev\DotNet\NServiceBus\src\host\NServiceBus.Host\Internal\GenericHost.cs:line 56
```

Everything works fine if I run the host using my own account, but if I run the host as a service with domain credentials or use those same credentials with the RunAs command I get the above exception. What are the permissions I need to configure so the service will work?

Here's my config:

```
        var configure = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .Log4Net<Log4NetLoggerAdapter>(a => { })
            .UnityBuilder(container)
            .XmlSerializer()
            .RijndaelEncryptionService()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage();

        configure.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<MsmqSubscriptionStorage>(
                    ComponentCallModelEnum.None).ConfigureProperty(p => p.DontUseExternalTransaction
                    , true
                );

        IBus bus = configure.UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(true)
            .LoadMessageHandlers()
            .Sagas()
            .NHibernateSagaPersister()
        .CreateBus()
        .Start();
```

And I have a NServiceBus.Host.exe.config file with the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: definitely a permissions problem, I added the service account to the local administrator group and everything works fine. Anyone know what permissions I need to set?

Comment: when I revoke admin permissions, but grant full control to the user on the folder I get the "attempt to write to readonly database" error. BTW the service is installed in the "Program Folders" directory. However, it was installed to run as a service and I have checked it has permission to "logon as service".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you *temporarily* give EVERYONE and ANONYMOUS LOGON Full Control over the directory specified?  If that solves the exception, it's definitely a security issue.  Are you using |DataDirectory| in your connection string?  Are you sure the process is actually looking at the directory that you think it's looking at?

Following that, I would try using the SQLite in memory connection string settings to see if it's able to at least create a database and use it:

`":memory:;Version=3;New=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;"`

The above string uses in-memory SQLite but keeps a single connection open so that the tables and data continue to exist until the process exits.

Another strategy that I would use is to change the saga persister to another SQL flavor, such as MS SQL to see if that solves it.

Comment: fired up Filemon and confirmed it. It was trying to create the sqlite database in \Windows\System32. I changed the connection string to use "data source=|DataDirectory|\sagas.sqlite;......" and that fixed it. As always, thanks Jonathan!